# Does Cordova Library work on Android 2.3.3?

Tags: android, cordova

On the Cordova website, (http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) it says that Android 2.3 is supported. However I'm working on an app and it does not work when I set the project build target to Android 2.3. It works for Android 3 and above. Why does it not work for 2.3? Are there any substitutes?

Comment: There is no reason phone gap shouldn't work on 2.3. Do you have the sdk for 2.3 downloaded? In any case, even if you don't have that sdk downloaded/installed, you should still be able to compile it for a higher level and set the min sdk to a lower level.

Comment: When I add the Cordova source code to my project, it's references to HONEYCOMB and IC_CREAM_SANDWICH etc. break the compiler. Do you think trying a different build target would fix this? How come when I test the application on 2.3.3 it just flat out does not work?




There also seems to be some sort of issue with the android webkit. It says the import of webkit.WebResourceResponse and webkit.JavascrptInterface both cannot be resolved. When I switch the build target from 2.3.3 or SDK 10 to SDK 17 or 15 or above 10 really, these problems go away?